# store rows of a data.frame are equal to top.20. in frequens from column as factor i.e names

Tags: r

The data.frame (d1.csv) looks like:

```
Age Height Weight     Sport
23    170     60      Judo
33    193    125 Athletics
```

I have to make a ny data.frame like d2 with the top 20 an shall use this charachters below stored in

```
names(top.20.sports)

 [1] "Athletics"       "Swimming"        "Football"        "Rowing"
```

... and have to use `match()` or `%in%` like to use `subset()` like d1 with subset = Sport %in% names(top.20.sports).

I tried several things bud I'm new at this and am missing something...

```
d2<-subset(d1, (Sport %in% names(top.20.sports)))
```

gives the hole list, same as with

```
d2 <- d1[d1$Sport %in% names(top.20.sports),]
```

match gives me a bunch (42) with "NA"

```
d2<-d1[,tolower(names(top.20.sports)) %in% d1[,4]]
Dataframe with 0 colomns und 9038 rows
```

(9038 rows are correct bud where is the data?)

Comment: When you used `tolower` it made the names all lower case and failed to match names that are capitalized.

Comment: Thanks, same with toupper or casefold bud I see it has no meaning to use it anyway, nor?

Comment: If `subset(d1, (Sport %in% names(top.20.sports)))` gives the _whole_ list then .... it is what it is. All of the Sport entries are in the top-20.

Comment: Yes, you are right! It has stuff like: "Cycling - Mountain Bike, Cycling - Road, Cycling - Track" bud only "Cycling - Road" and "Cycling - Track" are in the top twenty. How can I pick out just for exempel  "Cycling - Road"  with out all other combination of cycling?? There are other odd combination within sports.

Comment: First of we need a ban on indefinite pronouns like "it". What is the name of the object that `has stuff like: "Cycling - Mountain Bike, Cycling - Road, Cycling - Track"`?

Comment: Then things have gotten too confusing for me. There were only two objects before; d1 and top.20.sports.

Comment: Ok, there is the objekt d1 with for columns and over 10000 rows. The object top.20.sports is made from column 4 after doing sport<-as.data.frame(table(d1[4]));   sport[order(sport$Freq),] ; sport_sort<-sort(table(d1[4]), decreasing = TRUE); top.20.sports<-sport_sort[1:20];.
It's from a file about Athletic Body Diversity Reference for Artists. Ithink I have to understand this: x[, 1, drop = F] or x[1]

Comment: Thanks for your try BondedDust

Answer (score 0):

There was no error, like   BondedDust told me: "If subset(d1, (Sport %in% names(top.20.sports))) gives the whole list then .... it is what it is. All of the Sport entries are in the top-20."
Just it never was the hole list...:

I was thinking I had 10384 rows

-10384  24    221    110      Basketball-

Basketball as the last one. Bud the number of the row is not the number of the rows:

> nrow(d2)

[1] 8009

> dim(d2)

[1] 8009    4